# Changing string "members" to "articles" in MediaWiki category pages

Tags: mediawiki

I want to change the word "member" in Special:Categories to "articles" but I can't seem to find which file I have to modify. If someone could direct me to the file (and the line if possible) it would be great! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit `MediaWiki:Nmembers` to change this message for the default language of your wiki.
Edit `MediaWiki:Nmembers/ar` (default “عضو واحد”), `MediaWiki:Nmembers/fr` (default “$1 membres”), `MediaWiki:Nmembers/en`(default “$1 members”), etc, to set it for other languages that your users might be using.

To see what message corresponds to a certain text in your wiki's interface, add `uselang=qqx` to the url, e.g. `//mywiki.com/wiki/Special:Categories?uselang=qqx` (or `//mywiki.com/w/index.php?title=Special:Categories&uselang=qqx`, or whatever url structure you have).

All messages will be replaced with their *names* in paranthesis, eg `(categories)`. This tells you that you can change the text that occurs in that position by editing `MediaWiki:Categories`, `MediaWiki:Categories/en`, `MediaWiki:Categories/hi`, etc.

`qqx` is a special language code for this purpose. You can use the same function to preview your wiki in any supported language, by adding `uselang=sv`, `uselang=ja`, etc, to any page url.

On `Special:AllMessages`, you can see all system messages, and also keep track of those modified on your wiki.

Editing the source files, as suggested in the question, is a bad idea for many reasons. Most importantly, the changes will be overwritten on the next upgrade.

Comment: Thanks alot! I solved my problem and learned something new! Thumps up!